# Fourier transform and (anti)derivatives

Tags: integration, derivatives, fourier-transform

Using this equality:

$ \mathcal{F} \left(\frac{d^nf(x)}{dx^n}\right) = (i 2\pi u)^n F(u) $

I remember my professor saying that if $n=-1$ we would be able to get $ \int f(x) dx $, is this true? If so, how precise it is? Will it work with any kind of $f(x)$?

IIRC he also said we could use any $n$, even non integers, if possible, does it have any practical use?

Comment: on the left do you mean to say $\frac{d^nf(x)}{dx^n}$?

Comment: @HenryLee yes, my bad

Comment: I guess if the 'opposite' to differentiating is integrating, then $\frac{d^{-1}}{dx^{-1}}f(x)=\int f(x)dx$. And partial differential do exist, see this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus .

Comment: In particular this formula is useful: $$D^af(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-a)}\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x\frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^a}dt$$

Answer (score 0):

If $f=g'$ then $\mathcal F (f)=\mathcal F (g')=(2\pi i u) \mathcal F (g)$. Hence $\mathcal F (g)=\frac 1 {2\pi i u} \mathcal F (f)=(2\pi i u )^{-1}\mathcal F (f)$. This is the Fourier transfom of $g=\int f$. This is valid under the condition $\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} f(x)\, dx =0$ (in addition to the obvious integrability conditions).